# Filesystem hooking

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Im making a virtual filesystem library that i want to add to any .exes
to accomplish this i need to hook all windows file functions.

I know that there are a lot of those functions but they are high level API, is there any comprehensive list of low level functions used by these ?

what i mean is ZwOpenFile <- NtOpenFile <- OpenFile etc (but only usermode)

What i need is the minimal possible set of funcs to hook to cover the whole filesystem handling. its a bit hard reversing this from windows API.

I have the basics covered (file reading only now and for sure not complete) but i also need file write / directory enum.

What is wierd is that for example `FindFirstFileA` uses `ZwOpenFile`

```
ZwOpenFile hook. ObjectName : \??\D:\VFS\* Handle : 20
NtQueryDirectoryFileHook hook. Handle : 20
NtQueryDirectoryFileHook hook. Handle : 20
D:/VFS/Test
D:/VFS/test2.txt
D:/VFS/test3.txt
NtQueryDirectoryFileHook hook. Handle : 20
ZwOpenFile hook. ObjectName : \??\D:\VFS\Test\* Handle : 24
NtQueryDirectoryFileHook hook. Handle : 24
NtQueryDirectoryFileHook hook. Handle : 24
D:/VFS/Test/huh.txt
NtQueryDirectoryFileHook hook. Handle : 24
ZwOpenFile hook. ObjectName : \??\C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll Handle : 44
```

Functions of interest :

```
NtCreateFile
NtOpenFile
NtLockFile
NtUnlockFile
NtReadFile
NtWriteFile
NtClose

NtWriteFileGather
NtReadFileScatter

NtQueryDirectoryFile

NtQueryInformationFile
NtSetInformationFile

related


NtQueryVolumeInformationFile
MapViewOfFile
NtOpenSection
NtUnmapViewOfSection

NtFsControlFile
NtDeviceIoControlFile
NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile
```

Comment: http://www.openrce.org/reference_library/win32_call_chains/XPSP2/KERNEL32 i really dont want to dig thru all this

Comment: Would it not be better to write a filesystem filter driver?

Comment: Thats the exact opposite of what i want to do.. i want the exe and its assets (including dlls inis etc) in one file (if modified saved on hdd), here im installing a driver on the clients machine ;/

Comment: Agree with Mats. An EXE would be entirely the wrong solution. Drivers are accessible to all programs via the kernel, but an EXE runs under a specific user account and thus is hard to access from other accounts.

Comment: And user mode hooks will have no effect on code in kernel mode that tries to open a file. The right way to do this is write a file system redirector. Simulating a network drive is probably going to let you leverage a lot of infrastructure that already exists in the system to do exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: I dont want them to have effect on kernel mode code, i dont spoof other applications filesystems only mine. For sure i will not write a driver here because 1) it totally changes the whole project 2) i dont feel confident putting drivers on someones system, i doubt they will be secure.

Comment: If you aren't hooking kernel mode, then your solution is not complete. A user mode app can pass a file name to kernel mode, and kernel mode opens the file. (e.g. RegLoadHive.) Noy sure what you mean by "doubt they will be secure." Your hook is already not secure.

Comment: My hook is not secure ? exactly how you judge that you seen the code ? it is less secure than exposing the targets kernel to exploits?? i am hooking the "gateway" of the app to kernel mode so how will it pass a filename to kernel mode? it passes via the functions i hook :)) you seem to defend your idea of writing kernel drivers at all cost, well im a bit different i avoid doing things in kernel unless 100% unbypassable. Im not writing an antivirus here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ZwCreateFile for hooking file opening or creating; ZwDeleteFile for hooking file deleting; also you need ZwLockFile and ZwUnlockFile if you want to control file locking; hooking ZwQueryInformationFile and ZwSetInformationFile will help you to detect changes in file information. You also need to hook ZwReadFile and ZwWriteFile if you want to control reading from file and writing to it; and ZwMapViewOfSection / ZwUnmapViewOfSection to work with file mappings.

For directory enum you need to hook ZwQueryDirectoryFile.

All of these functions can easily be hooked from usermode.

Comment: Im allready doing that (parts anyway), but will it cover all possible high level api ? my experience with windows internals tell me that there are some wierd functions laying around to stab me in the back :)

Comment: I am sure that it's enough to cover all basic file operations. All high level APIs call these Zw* services anyway.

Comment: What version of Windows do you use? I've looked in debugger now and there are no NOPs before Zw* functions :(

Comment: right they are just pad nops from previous function, i looked wrong

Comment: A bigger problem is that FindFirstFileA uses ZwOpenFile o0 i feel countless hours under debugger incoming, anyway i accept your answer ty.